# A Toffoli gate can be decomposed into a circuit of 1- and 2-qubit gates

Tags: quantum-gate, resource-request

While reseaching a way to implement a 3 qubit Toffoli gate, I came across this [circuit](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs191/fa07/lectures/lecture9_fa07.pdf):

> [image: Blockquote]

However, I cannot find a proper source for this circuit. Can anyone link a cited paper.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18275/10454

Answer (score 1):

I believe the origin is this paper:

arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016

publication: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.52.3457